# Automate the filling of an online form from Excel

Tags: automation

Here is my issue: At work, I have to input data into an online form manually from an excel sheet. Is it possible to tell the form to look at an excel sheet and grab the data itself?

I don't know where to start.

Comment: To improve you question clarity, it is important to specify your intention clearly by explaining what "tell the form" means . If you intend to automate the process, you can achieve this using programming languages such as Java or Python or any other. By writing code, you can extract data from an excel file and use Selenium or other libraries to automate the online form filling process.